# Python - Is there an NLTK Corpus for english GB words?

Tags: python, nltk

I am in the process of learning Python and trying to create an anagram creator/solver in flask.

I'm using nltk and have a basic script set up which descrambles a group of letters and finds the word from the corpus. I know my method may not be perfect - remember I'm still learning what is available to do in Python - but it works in principle and I've created a similar script to find all the words within a group of letters.

My problem is that it only uses American English, so in the example below 'favro' becomes 'favor' which is the American spelling, but 'favrou' doesn't become 'favour' which is the British spelling.

```
import itertools
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import words
english_vocab = set(w.lower() for w in nltk.corpus.words.words())
scramble = "favro"
sep = ""
for y in list(itertools.permutations(scramble, len(scramble))):
    if (sep.join(y) in english_vocab):
        print(sep.join(y))
```

Is there anything out there which distinguishes between American and British English?

I've tried to use 'enchant' and it works fine on the solver part, but when I try to create a list of words within a word it is incredibly slow. For example, when I try to find all the words within 'colours' nltk takes 0.08 seconds and enchant takes 2.5 seconds. This time difference increases as the number of letters increases, so enchant is not viable.

Any ideas?

Steve

Answer (score 0):

If you're only using NLTK for a word corpus, you might just want to find a word list of British-English words and read that in instead.

Since we're talking anagram solvers, why not use the SOWPODS word list, as used in official Scrabble competitions?

For instance, https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jesstess/Scrabble/master/scrabble/sowpods.txt (warning: big file!) contains `FAVOUR`, so it should work for you.

**EDIT:** To elaborate on my comment, e.g.

```
from collections import defaultdict

ws = defaultdict(set)

for word in open("./sowpods.txt"):
    word = word.lower().strip()
    if word:
        ws[frozenset(word)].add(word)


def find(word):
    return ws[frozenset(word)]


print(find("wired"))
```

outputs

```
{'rewired', 'weirdie', 'wiredrew', 'dewier', 'weired', 'widder', 'wried', 'weird', 'weirded', 'weedier', 'wider', 'wired', 'weirder'}
```

in 0.7 seconds.

(Yes, that's a superset of the possible words, but it's easy to filter down. Another option that would avoid this is to use `''.join(sorted(word))` as the key for the dict.)

Comment: Thanks @akx, the file import is the route I'm going to go in probably. I've created a script to split a large file, such as the one you mentioned into smaller files based on word size, which will then speed up the main script.

Comment: @SteveH You don't necessarily need to split the large file into smaller files... you could read it into a dict keyed by `frozenset(word)`, with values as sets of full words. That way finding anagrams is as easy as looking up by `frozenset(word)` :)

Comment: I decided to go down a different route and came up with this https://github.com/StephenH69/Python-Word-Solvers. A lot quicker and now more suitable for use on a website. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can trivially speed up `splitwordlist` by an empirical 50x by not opening and closing the file(s) for each word. Also, use `\n` for a separator, not `\r` :)